# Getting started designing and implementing an idea for Android App

Tags: android

Does anyone have any good references for designing and implementing an idea I have for an android application.

My idea is for an application that stores information and reviews about a specific location and presents this information to user.

I have gone through all the tutorials and have been reading up on anything and everything about android. Now I am ready to challenge myself with my first app.

Any suggestions on getting started would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Formula1 Live Timing - this is missing from Android

Comment: on http://www.formula1.com there is a Live Timing session for practice, qualifying and race. This currently is not available as an Android app, although iPhone and some other versions already do exists.